# Javascript: Is an empty object a falsy one?

Tags: javascript

The empty object is undefined, like this `var empty_obj = {}`.

An undefined will be a false one. But I notice that
`empty_obj || 3` will return `empty_obj` not `3`.

Why is that?

Comment: Why should it be falsy? Its perfectly reasonable to have all objects be truthy and in fact many other languages will do that.

Comment: Try `if (Object.keys(obj).length)` to check if empty

Comment: [How to Check if Object is Empty in JavaScript](https://www.samanthaming.com/tidbits/94-how-to-check-if-object-is-empty/)

Comment: `if (!obj)` would have been so nice to have...

Answer (score 114, accepted):

The empty object is **not** undefined.

```
console.log({} === undefined); // false
console.log(typeof {}); // object
```

It is a truthy value:

```
if ({}) console.log('truthy'); // truthy
```

It even has some properties:

```
console.log(typeof {}.hasOwnProperty); // function
```

The only falsy values in JS are `0`, `false`, `null`, `undefined`, empty string, and `NaN`.

---

You may be confused by the return value of `var =` statements. These will always show as `undefined` in the Chrome console:

```
> var obj = {}
undefined
> var x = 100
undefined
> var y = "potato"
undefined
```

Just because the `var =` statement returns undefined doesn't mean the value was undefined. Although, without the `var`, assignments do return the value being assigned:

```
> obj = {}
{}
> x = 100
100
> y = "potato"
"potato"
```

Comment: Why does `{} == true` return false?

Comment: @KevinBowersox "truthy" !== `== true`. `{} == false` also returns false. `"some string" == true` also returns false.

Comment: note that you can simulate a boolean compare operator with extra bangs; alert(!!{} == !!true) to see if two vars boolean compare the same. since you're doing it to both, you can shorten it to alert(!{} == !true) and yield the same results as a double bang. you can also use the + prefix to compare as a number; alert(+"4"==+4), and ""+ to compare as a string; alert(""+5==""+"5").

Comment: Note that `document.all` is also falsy.

Comment: for others, by "truthy" it means, `Truth Value` in python.

Answer (score 12):

As mentioned in above answers empty object is not falsy value in JavaScript,

**how to check if obj is empty correctly?**

```
Object.keys(obj).length === 0 && obj.constructor === Object
```

> Why do we need an additional constructor check?

You may be wondering why do we need the constructor check. Well, it's to cover for the wrapper instances. In JavaScript, we have 9 built-in constructors.

```
new String();
new Number();
new Boolean();
new Array();
new RegExp();
new Function();
new Date();
```

So we can create an empty object with new Object(). Side note: you should NEVER create an object using the constructor. It's considered bad practice.

```
const obj = new Object();

Object.keys(obj).length === 0; // true
```

So just using the Object.keys, it does return true when the object is empty. But ***doesn't work*** when we create a new object instance using these other constructors

```
Object.keys(new String()).length === 0 // false
```

hence constructor check is necessary for object instance

```js
function isEmptyObj(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).length === 0 && obj.constructor === Object;
}

console.log(isEmptyObj({}));
```

**P.S**

this snippet only works for objects don't use for undefined or null

Comment: Just checked and: Object.keys(new String()).length === 0 // true   
The problem is with Date() object:

Answer (score 3):

The empty object is not undefined, only objects of type `undefined`<sup>1</sup> are undefined:

```
[timwolla@~]node
> undefined == {}
false
> typeof {}
'object'
> typeof undefined
'undefined'
```

<sup>1</sup> It is possible to redefine `undefined`, when not using strict mode. Checking with `typeof` or against `void 0` is safer.

Comment: Thank you @TimWolla, I see your points. When i test it using chrome console, the chrome replies undefined after I typing var obj={}

Comment: @Bargitta Sure, it replies undefined after you type `var x = 100` as well. `var =` assignments always return undefined.

Answer (score 2):

You have defined `empty_obj` as an object that happens to not have any defined properties but it is defined. For that reason `empty_obj` results in a truthy value and returns in the assignment.

```
var myobj = {}; //defined
var myobj2;     //undefined

if(myobj == undefined)
{
    console.log("myobj is undefined");
}
if(myobj2 == undefined)
{
    console.log("the 2nd one is undefined");
}
if(myobj)
{
    console.log("myobj isn't falsy");
}
if(myobj2)
{
     console.log("myobj2 isn't false");
}
```