# Object does not equal to true or false

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

So my uploaded media file (event.target.files[0]) does not equal to true or false.
It has a `typeof object`.

It's part of some form state and I'd like to check the object whether all fields are not empty `""`.

I thought a JS object should always === true, but maybe this is different for 'files' objects?

Comment: Can you show your code so this can be narrowed down by the community?

Comment: hard to figure out what you are talking about.

Comment: An object won’t strictly equal true; an object is truthy, but that’s not what strict-equal checks for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`===` checks for [strict equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality), so the two values must be **exactly** the same.

[An object is truthy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21743921), but **does not** equal `true`, so what you are really doing is `{ ... } === true`, which is `false`.

---

If you want to check if none of the object's values are empty, you can [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for empty values:

```js
const empty = Object.keys(theObject).length === 0 || Object.values(theObject).filter(value => {
  return value.trim() === '';
}).length > 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

`===` tests for equal value and equal type ([ref](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp)). `typeof(true)` is `boolean` but a file is not a boolean. So the comparison will never yield true.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/8511350/4640820

Answer (score -1):

To check the type of a value, you must write

```js
if( (typeof <your value>) == ("<expected type>")){
   ...
}
```

For example, a statement like this:

```js
if( (typeof 42)=="number" )
```

is **true**.

[Reference for most cases of **typeof**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)

Comment: This isn't idiomatic, an `if (o)` would be more than sufficient here.