# When I am testing for truthiness, why is my Object.create(null) value true while null is false?

Tags: javascript, null, equality, type-coercion, truthiness

I am trying to confirm for myself whether a null object is false.
First, I tried to create a null object using Object.create(null).
Then I decided to test this object against null.

I wrote a snippet of code to check for truthiness:

```
let emptyObject = {};
let nullObject = Object.create(null);
console.log(typeof nullObject);

console.log(Boolean(null));
console.log(Boolean(nullObject));
console.log(Boolean(emptyObject));
```

But my output is the following:

```
object
false
true
true
```

The `nullObject` is not empty nor undefined, but why does it not have the same truthy value as `null`? Are these not both values of `null` with object type, `object`?

Comment: Does this answer your question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21743921/javascript-is-an-empty-object-a-falsy-one

Comment: `Object.create(null)` still gives you an object, not an actual `null`. The only difference is that the prototype is not set but type and equality don't rely on that anyway.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript: Is an empty object a falsy one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21743921/javascript-is-an-empty-object-a-falsy-one)

Comment: Also relevant: [Creating JS object with Object.create(null)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15518328)

Comment: I didn't know a null object was still considered empty. I tried to equate emptyObject == nullObject. I know that an emptyObject is truthy.